# Wrong asin result

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

My code:

```
import math
x = input()
print(math.asin(math.radians(float(x))))
```

My x was 0.7071067811865475, and the result was some irracional number between 0 and 1, but in my knowledge it should have been around 45

Comment: `x` isn't an angle at all, so converting it to radians makes no sense. Also -- when conversion is appropriate -- you need to convert to degrees, not radians.

Comment: You're converting the wrong number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's impossible to expect good results when the problem isn't understood.

Answer (score 2):

You're converting the wrong number with the wrong function.

```
>>> import math
>>> x = 0.7071067811865475
>>> math.degrees(math.asin(x))
44.99999999999999
>>>
```

That is, given `x` (which is the sine of an angle) call [`asin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.asin) to compute the angle (in radians), and then use [`degrees`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.degrees) to convert that angle to degrees.

Answer (score 1):

`math.radians` converts **to** radians, you want `math.degrees`.

It's also in the wrong place, you're converting a number, not an angle. You want

```
print(math.degrees(math.asin(float(x))))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#angular-conversion